# What is this bee-like insect flying above the swallow in Singapore?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Photo was taken within the past week in the Singapore Botanical Garden. The bird is the Pacific swallow *Hirundo tahitica*, but there is also an unidentified insect flying above the bird, which is sizing up the insect. The insect wandered into the frame of view while attempting to photograph the bird, which was the reason that it is out of focus.

The insect appears to be about 1cm long, and has the black and yellow colouration as well as wing shape of a bee, but the mouthpiece doesn't appear to resemble any species of bee or wasp that I am aware of. What could this insect be?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that's some sort of nectar feeding moth. Search for ones that mimic bee or wasps.